# RelativeLayout check runtime if is removed or not

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

In an `activity` I am changing one of the `ViewGroup` content runtime: buttons action, other events.

At a specific case I need to check if a child is in this `layout` or not ( in this case the child is another `RelativeLayout`, which hold other views)

How can I check runtime, programmatically if `child_1_RelativeLayout` is there or is already removed from view tree, his parent is `parentRelativeLayout`

The [getParent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) is usefully? - not much explanation how to use it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have stored your views you can use [getParent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) to check if view is a direct child for other view. After removing view its parent field will be cleared. For example:

```
ViewGroup parent = ...;
View child = ...;

assert(child.getParent() == parent); // <-- true

parent.removeView(child);

assert(child.getParent() == parent); // <-- false
```

Comment: +1, if(child != null && child.getParent() != null){ /*it is on view tree*/}else{/* not initialized, or is removed already*/}, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if I understand your question correctly, but:

- when you add the relative layout, be sure to first give it an id (either in your layout.xml file, or from code)
- to check existence of the relative layout within the `ViewGroup`, use ViewGroup's `findViewById()` method (inherited from `View`) and pass it the id you've given to the relative layout
- if it returns null, the relative layout is not there, otherwise `findViewById()` will find it

So in short, `findViewById()` is not only defined for an Activity, but you can call this on any view you would like to use as a starting point for your search.

Comment: +1, thanks I forgot the idea with findViewbyId, beacuse I have cached the reference and  Iam working with that